# Only works in debugging mode

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create a program for a distributed system. At the moment I have a thread for listening to connections, and a thread for sending, and a thread for receiving.

I've reached a problem where the client will connect but only when using breakpoints. I can't figure out the problem at all!. I've tried to implement things to slow the program down however nothing is working.

If you guys could take a look i'd be greatly appreciative.

```js
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Server starting on port 5000");  
        RecievingConnection reciever = new RecievingConnection(5000,0); //Recieving Connection
        reciever.start();
        SendingConnection sender = new SendingConnection(5001,1); //Sending Connection
        sender.start();
        
        while(true){
            while(reciever.ready==true){ 
            System.out.println("In");
            nodes first = new nodes(reciever.socket,0);
            System.out.println("Node created");
            first.start();
            System.out.println("Client connected on port: " + reciever.socket.getLocalAddress());
            nodes second = new nodes(sender.socket,1);
            second.start();
            reciever.ready=false;
            sender.ready=false;
            reciever.connectionComplete=true;
            sender.connectionComplete=true;
            }

        }

    }
```

```js
    public RecievingConnection(int port, int mode)
    {
        Serverport = port;
        connectionMode = mode;
        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            server.setSoTimeout(100000);
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
    public void run(){  
            while(true){
                if(ready == false){
                    try {
                        socket = server.accept();
                        ready = true;
                        System.out.println("Attempting to connect using port: " + Serverport);
                        while(connectionComplete == false){
                            //wait
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    }    
                }

            }
        }
```

The sending thread is basically the same code. Any idea what the problem is? "Nodes" is the thread for each node.

Comment: Seems you need proper sync between your threads. I suggest  Oracle threading tutorial as a starting point.

Comment: Would making the thread wait, until the main thread notify it after the nodes have been created?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost certainly at:

```
    while (connectionComplete == false) {
        //wait
    }
```

This will loop forever, the other thtreads will not get any cpu time at all. It also explains why it works in debug - it's because in debug if you stop at a breakpoint, any other threads will get time.

You should at least do:

```
    while (connectionComplete == false) {
        //wait
        Thread.sleep(0);
    }
```

and maybe use a number much greater than `0`. This will allow other thtreads a chance to run.

I am not suggesting that this will make your code work correctly but it should remove the current problem.

---

After that there's another tight loop that won't let any other thread time.

```
    while (true) {
        if (ready == false) {
```

Change that to:

```
    while (true) {
        if (ready == false) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // Here too.
            Thread.sleep(0);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I've tried that, Still hangs, and doesn't seem to ever enter the while loop in the main program to create node threads. I'm lost entirely. The main thread program should change "Connectioncomplete" to true once the nodes have been created

Comment: @JamieBarnett - See my edit. Please try to understand why these stop your program working.

Comment: I'm fairly new to java as you may notice. I don't quite understand why this is happening. I figured that the while loop would run until the condition is met, and other threads would perform their action? Your solution did fix it though. Thank you

Comment: @JamieBarnett - The Java threading architecture simulates multithreading (sort of) so it even works on single-core units. To achieve this it must be given the opportunity to switch between threads. A loop without `sleep()` or something like that will never let the JVM in to do any thread-switching.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a sleep in the main thread. I presume this is because the main thread takes priority over child threads?

Comment: No, it does not. Maybe that did the thread to clean it's cache so one thread can read the other's variables updated or you have a race condition somewhere. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Answer (score 0):

You can't just share variables between threads. Make them volatile, synchronize or use CAS types like AtomicBoolean.

Read about it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html

http://www.journaldev.com/1061/java-synchronization-and-thread-safety-tutorial-with-examples

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html

Besides class "nodes" is not described here and classes are expected to start with an upper case letter.